# Ruby "rake test:units" failure

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am running a unit test on a user model in ruby. I am still learning ruby. So when I run

```
rake test:units
```

I get this

```
Loaded suite /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/rake_test_loader
Started
F
Finished in 0.116562 seconds.

  1) Failure:
test_user_attributes_must_not_be_empty(UserTest) [test/unit/user_test.rb:10]:
<false> is not true.

1 tests, 5 assertions, 1 failures, 0 errors
rake aborted!
Command failed with status (1): [/usr/bin/ruby1.8 -I"lib:test" "/usr/lib/ru...]

Tasks: TOP => test:units
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

when I go to file `test/unit/user_test.rb:10` I see this line,

```
require 'test_helper'

    class UserTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase
       test "user attributes must not be empty" do
            user = User.new
        assert user.invalid?
        assert user.errors[:username].any?
        assert user.errors[:name].any?
        assert user.errors[:surname].any?
        >>>assert user.errors[:date_birth].any?<<< Here!
        assert user.errors[:date_reg].any?
        assert user.errors[:email].any?
   end
end
```

so what is it causing the error? Why am I getting the error there and not anywhere else? like username?

Edit: 
My User Class:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

validates :username, :name, :surname, :email, :presence => true
validates :username, :uniqueness => true

end
```

Comment: Show us what `User.new` outputs in the console please.

Comment: `rails c` will bring up a rails initialized irb console and you can execute code interactively there...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What your tests are saying is that if there is any error on all those attributes then the test pass.

You don't have a validation on `date_birth`, so no error is raised, so the test doesn't pass.